# Efficiently constructing sparse biadjacency matrix in Numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, graph

I'm trying to load this CSV file into a sparse numpy matrix, which would represent the biadjacency matrix of this user-to-subreddit bipartite graph: http://figshare.com/articles/reddit_user_posting_behavior/874101

Here's a sample:

```
603,politics,trees,pics
604,Metal,AskReddit,tattoos,redditguild,WTF,cocktails,pics,funny,gaming,Fitness,mcservers,TeraOnline,GetMotivated,itookapicture,Paleo,trackers,Minecraft,gainit
605,politics,IAmA,AdviceAnimals,movies,smallbusiness,Republican,todayilearned,AskReddit,WTF,IWantOut,pics,funny,DIY,Frugal,relationships,atheism,Jeep,Music,grandrapids,reddit.com,videos,yoga,GetMotivated,bestof,ShitRedditSays,gifs,technology,aww
```

There are 876,961 lines (one per user) and 15,122 subreddits and a total of 8,495,597 user-to-subreddit associations.

Here's the code which I have right now, and which takes 20 minutes to run on my MacBook Pro:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix 

row_list = []
entry_count = 0
all_reddits = set()
with open("reddit_user_posting_behavior.csv", 'r') as f:
    for x in f:
        pieces = x.rstrip().split(",")
        user = pieces[0]
        reddits = pieces[1:]
        entry_count += len(reddits)
        for r in reddits: all_reddits.add(r)
        row_list.append(np.array(reddits))

reddits_list = np.array(list(all_reddits))

# 5s to get this far

rows = np.zeros((entry_count,))
cols = np.zeros((entry_count,))
data =  np.ones((entry_count,))
i=0
user_idx = 0
for row in row_list:
    for reddit_idx in np.nonzero(np.in1d(reddits_list,row))[0]:
        cols[i] = user_idx
        rows[i] = reddit_idx
        i+=1
    user_idx+=1
adj = csr_matrix( (data,(rows,cols)), shape=(len(reddits_list), len(row_list)) )
```

It seems hard to believe that this is as fast as this can go... Loading the 82MB file into a list of lists takes 5s but building out the sparse matrix takes 200 times that. What can I do to speed this up? Is there some file format that I can convert this CSV into in less than 20min that would import more quickly? Is there some obviously-expensive operation I'm doing here that's not good? I've tried building a dense matrix and I've tried creating a `lil_matrix` and a `dok_matrix` and assigning the `1`'s one at a time, and that's no faster.

Comment: What's the time fot the double for loop?  The csr call?  I'd first try to vectorize the inner for loop, that is, assign multiple values at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't sleep, tried one last thing... I was able to get it down to 10 seconds this way, in the end:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix 

user_ids = []
subreddit_ids = []
subreddits = {}
i=0
with open("reddit_user_posting_behavior.csv", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for sr in line.rstrip().split(",")[1:]: 
            if sr not in subreddits: 
                subreddits[sr] = len(subreddits)
            user_ids.append(i)
            subreddit_ids.append(subreddits[sr])
        i+=1

adj = csr_matrix( 
    ( np.ones((len(userids),)), (np.array(subreddit_ids),np.array(user_ids)) ), 
    shape=(len(subreddits), i) )
```

Comment: What the words corresponding to each row of `adj`?  Looks like you have to sort the `subreddits` keys based on the values?

Answer (score 1):

For a start you could replace in the inner `for` with something like:

```
reddit_idx = np.nonzero(np.in1d(reddits_list,row))[0]
sl = slice(i,i+len(reddit_idx))
cols[sl] = user_idx
rows[sl] = reddit_idx
i = sl.stop
```

The use of `nonzero(in1d())` to find the matches looks good, but I haven't explored alternatives.  An alternative to assignment via slices is to `extend` lists, but that is probably slower, especially with many rows.

Constructing the rows, cols is by far the slowest part.  The call to `csr_matrix` is minor.

Since there are a lot more rows (users) than subreddits, it might be worth collecting, for each subreddit, a list of user ids.  You are already collecting subreddits in a set.  You could, instead, collecte them in a default dictionary, and build the matrix from that.  When tested on your 3 lines replicated 100000 times it is noticeably faster.

```
from collections import defaultdict
red_dict = defaultdict(list)
user_idx = 0
with open("reddit_user_posting_behavior.csv", 'r') as f:
    for x in f:
        pieces = x.rstrip().split(",")
        user = pieces[0]
        reddits = pieces[1:]
        for r in reddits:
            red_dict[r] += [user_idx]
        user_idx += 1

print 'done 2nd'
x =  red_dict.values()
adj1 = sparse.lil_matrix((len(x), user_idx), dtype=int)
for i,j in enumerate(x):
    adj1[i,j] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It runs in about 14 seconds on my machine but the final output doesn't look right. The first row-sum should be in the 10,000 range but for this output it's 1. I was able to use a somewhat similar approach with a single pass and a dictionary to get it down to 10 seconds, if you look at my answer.

Comment: My `adj1` matches your original `adj`.  Your 2nd script produces a different `adj`.  I think they have the same row counts, but in a different order - dictionary order v order of occurrence?