# How to create a large but sparse dataframe from a dict efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large but very sparse matrix(50,000 rows*100,000 columns, only 10% of the values are known). Each known element of this matrix is a float number from 0.00 to 1.00 and these known values are stored in a python dict with a format like:

```
{'c1': {'r1':0.27, 'r3':0.45}, 
 'c2': {'r2':0.65, 'r4':0.87} }
```

Now the problem is how to construct a pandas.DataFrame from this dict efficiently? Here, efficiency includes both memory usage and time for constructing dataframe.

For memory usage, I'm hoping to store each element by np.uint8. Because the known value is from 0.00 to 1.00 and I only care about the first 2 digits, so I could cast it to a unsigned 8-bit integer via multiplying by 100. This might save a lot of memory storage for this dataframe.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to fill the missing value when constructing a DataFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559409/how-to-fill-the-missing-value-when-constructing-a-dataframe)

Comment: You may find my self-answer here helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160867/efficiently-constructing-sparse-biadjacency-matrix-in-numpy

Answer (score 0):

A `dict` like:

```
{'c1': {'r1':0.27, 'r3':0.45}, 
 'c2': {'r2':0.65, 'r4':0.87} }
```

... is best converted into a normalised structure like this:

```
 level0    level1   value
 c1        r1        0.27
 c1        r3        0.45
 c2        r2        0.65
 c2        r4        0.87
```

... than a pivot table like this:

```
      r1    r2    r3    r4
c1  0.27   nan  0.45   nan
c2   nan  0.65   nan  0.87
```

... since the latter takes much more memory.

A reasonably memory-efficient way of constructing the normalised structure is:

```
input = {'c1': {'r1':0.27, 'r3':0.45}, 
         'c2': {'r2':0.65, 'r4':0.87} }

result = []
for key, value in input.iteritems():
    row = pd.Series(value).reset_index()
    row.insert(0, 'key', key)
    result.append(row)

pd.concat(result, ignore_index=True)
```

This results in:

```
  key index     0
0  c2    r2  0.65
1  c2    r4  0.87
2  c1    r1  0.27
3  c1    r3  0.45
```

Comment: an answer for the author, but not a general solution for others. I do need a method to convert sparse data to pivot table.